# Как скрыть дивы все кроме дивов имеющих клас как у дива по котором кликнули?

Tags: javascript, jquery

К примеру есть несколько дивов, как при клике скрыть те дивы класы которых не равны класу дива по которому был совершон клик?

```html
<div class="n_1"></div>
<div class="n_1"></div>
<div class="n_2"></div>
<div class="n_2"></div>
```

если к примеру кликаем на див с класом n_1 то отсаються дивы:

```
<div class="n_1"></div>
<div class="n_1"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например, так

```
$('div').click(function() {
     $('div').not('.'+$(this).attr('class')).hide('slow')
})
```

[демо](https://jsfiddle.net/qwcphf3b/)